# Boolean form validation in play 2.2

Tags: forms, validation, playframework, boolean

I have a form - simple recruitment form. There's a question that the user need to select either "Yes" or "No". Let say the question is, "Are you bonded by scholarship?". If the user click on "Yes", there will be 2 Required fields -> the scholar provider and the duration of bond. Does anyone can help me on how to make the fields appear or auto-Required, if and only if the user select Yes?

If this condition doesn't make sense, I will then make the 2 fields appear without @Required, so that if user select No, they don't have to fill in the 2 fields. And if they select Yes, they should be aware that the next 2 fields is shouldn't be left empty.

Pls help me! :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing..
by default in your model do this-

```
schoolprovider="null" and duration="null"
```

then you can write javascript code to make the two fields appear when yes is selected.
then you can write a custom validate method which is like

```
if(bonded=="yes")
{ //check that school and duration are not null }
else 
{ //return badrequest() }
```

see the "defining constraints" for writing a custom validator--
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms